# Permission issue while creating hive external table in hdfs location

Tags: hive

Permission issue when creating hive external table in hdfs

Query:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`(     
id bigint,
name string,
Guid string
)
PARTITIONED BY(id bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION "hdfs://hivehostname:8020/tmp/external/test"
;
```

ERROR

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [username] does not have [ALL] privilege on
```

Comment: Normally no one creates table in tmp. Pls set a folder for this. Tmp is for temp system files and can be deleted anytime.

Comment: that tmp I created. Earlier it was working. I do have few folders inside that tmp folder. I also tried by using other folders as well. It is really strange why it is not working at this moment.

Comment: May be access level changed or location removed, not sure. You can connet to admin